# Android Gradle Plugin: Create AAR with Jar Dependencies and Proguard

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, proguard, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Gradle plugin 0.9 and Android Studio 0.5.4.

I have an Android Library Project with one dependency .jar inside /libs folder. When I run assembleRelease task with Proguard activated the resulting AAR has the following structure:

- MyLibrary

  - AndroidManifest.xml
  - assets/
  - libs/

    - myJar.jar
  - classes.jar
  - R.txt
  - res/

The problem is that myJar.jar classes get merged in classes.jar by Proguard (when I run without Proguard it doesn't happen). When I run my application project with AAR as a dependency I get "Multiple dex files define" errors regarding the myJar.jar classes that are also in classes.jar. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70873)﻿ was opened for this in Android Open Source Project.